# Duplicator plugin Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have developed WordPress website on my local PC. When I put site live on server it straight going to install only WordPress.

Please check the attached file step 1,2,3,4 then it goes to "WordPress Installation".

[Image showing steps followed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ3Dt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Do not select any **Advanced options**. Just do Next-Next and it will migrate your website successfully. And in case it doesn't work then the best way is to do this by using **All-in-One WP Migration**

Answer (score 0):

This behavior should not happen and is usually caused by a corrupted database or data that was not transferred properly. Here are a few things you can perform if you see this issue:

**OPTION 1:** Re-run the installer
Running the installer again can help validate if the issue is persistent.

- Be sure that ONLY the archive and installer.php files are present in the install directory.
- Clear your browser cache and re-run the install process
- Pay close attention to the install report and look for any possible errors or notices
- If the WordPress installer screen shows up a second time consider looking into options 2 & 3 below.

**OPTION 2:** Check log file

- After completing step 3 in the installer check the installer-log.txt
- Look for lines with **ERROR**. This indicates that data was not properly transfered to the new/existing database
- The installers MySQL server may not fully support the SQL script from the MySQL server where it was built
- See the following question for more details:
  What is Compatibility mode & 'Unknown collation' errors?

**OPTION 3:** Repair DB

- Run a repair and optimize on your database.
- Create a new package again
- Start over with a new install

Source:
    - Why is the WordPress installer showing up after I install?
    - https://snapcreek.com/duplicator/docs/faqs-tech/#faq-installer-230-q

Comment: i was found database problem. my local xampp server "utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci" and online server need "utf8mb4_unicode_ci". how to fix "utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci"  to "utf8mb4_unicode_ci"  ?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your plugin then recreate package. There is chance it wasn't created properly. Looks like it has problem creating your package zip file.

[screenshot install Duplicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2vin.jpg)